# Generic collection fixtures in XUnit

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit.net

A generic fixture and support classes:

```cs
public class Fixture<T> : IAsyncLifetime, IDisposable {
  public Fixture() { }
  public void Dispose() { }
  public Task InitializeAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;
  public Task DisposeAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;
}


[CollectionDefinition("collection")]
public class FixtureCollection<T> : ICollectionFixture<Fixture<T>> { }


[Collection("collection")]
public abstract class TestBase<T> {
  protected TestBase(Fixture<T> fixture) => _fixture = fixture;
  protected readonly Fixture<T> _fixture;
}
```

I stripped down those classes to show a minimal sample (but there is "stuff" in them).

And here's the test class:

```cs
public class Foo { }


public class Tests : TestBase<Foo> {
  public Tests(Fixture<Foo> fixture) : base(fixture) { }
  [Fact] public void Test1() { }
  [Fact] public void Test2() { }
}
```

Tests fail:

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: Fixture`1 fixture

If I make this change then it works, but I can't use it as a collection fixture:

```cs
//[Collection("collection")]                                      // removed
public abstract class TestBase<T> : IClassFixture<Fixture<T>> {   // added IClassFixture
```

I read [the docs](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context). Is this use case supported?

Comment: What do you aim to achieve by all this - even the TestBase is pointless - Xunit is specifically designed not to required or bring a burden of base classes? The main problem is that a Fixture needs to be a concrete type - Xunit creates Class Fixtures and Collection Fixtures on your behalf.

Comment: @RubenBartelink I stripped down all the classes so it's a minimal sample, so there's all sorts of stuff in those classes that I haven't shown. Do you know whether xunit support generic fixtures?

Comment: I am pretty sure it doesnt support generic fixtures. A CollectionDefinition or Collection that's open does not make sense in terms of how anything else works and I've never heard or seen of one despite watching this tag an the repo for years. Regardless of stripping down or not, I still don't get the `TestBase<T>` either - a) that's pretty much an antipattern that xUnit is seeking to avoid b) what does it achieve over creating a wrapper that you construct and assign to a field e.g. in the Test Class ctor.

Comment: @RubenBartelink Here's an [example](https://jeremydmiller.com/2021/09/07/integration-testing-ihost-lifecycle-with-xunit-net/) by jeremymiller of using a base testing class. Different from my use case but same class structure, except mine is generic. I'm not sure why it's an anti pattern. By the way a generic class works for a class fixture. Thanks for confirming it cannot be done for a collection fixture.

Comment: I get that a base class can work, but e.g. if AppFixture had `Host` and `Container` properties and you had an `app` Property, you'd be in the same position (though obv if you have a base class you can implement IDisposable / IAsyncDisposable). TL;DR It's a last resort thing more than a goto pattern for me, and I believe from the perspective of the design of xUnit.net. Two things that are very clear about Class and Collection fixtures though is that a) xUnit makes and owns them b) then passes them to the Test Class ctor.

Comment: Having said all that, if a CollectionAttribute is valid and picked up on a non-generic base class of a Test Class, then it would seem to be reasonable that it would be picked up on a generic one - that might be an impl oversight, or something that's harder or less efficient to achieve when walking the types to see which Test Classes are in which Collections. Personally, I'd tend to have a wrapper, wrappers or extension methods and keep a ref to the Collection Fixture as that Just Works, but thats obv subjective. Might make sense to ask why generic bases cant be in a collection on xunit github

Comment: @RubenBartelink Thanks for your thoughts, I will take them into account. I've opened a [discussion item](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/discussions/2425) on the repo. PS what sort of wrapper did you have in mind?

Comment: In terms or wrappers, [stuff like this](https://github.com/jet/dotnet-templates/blob/master/equinox-shipping/Watchdog.Integration/ReactorFixture.fs#L8 )[in this usage](https://github.com/jet/dotnet-templates/blob/master/equinox-shipping/Watchdog.Integration/WatchdogIntegrationTests.fs#L12) I make a fresh context per run of my property based test. I have a more complex case (not in that codebase) where it uses a Collection Fixture, but I make a local context in the Test Class which wraps access to the collection fixture; it routes a CC of the collectionfixture output to the ITestOutputSink etc